# How do I calculate the viscosity of a mixture of toluene and isopropanol?

Tags: electrochemistry, solvents

I am trying to understand why my nanoparticles will only electrophoretically deposit in a non-polar solvent and a non-polar/polar solvent mix but not in the polar solvent. I am hoping to use zeta potential and Hamaker's equation to understand this